# Dominios adicionales apuntan al principal en servidor

Tags: .htaccess, dominio

Tengo un servidor que tiene varios dominios apuntando a él. El caso es que al añadirle al dominio principal el certificado de seguridad SSL ahora algunos dominios apuntan al principal como por ejemplo https://dominioprincipal.es/carpetadondeapuntaotrodominio. En este caso el dominio adicional apunta a una carpeta pero como he puesto sale el dominio principal. 
Lo que quisiera es que el dominio adicional apunte a la carpeta y se muestre sin el dominio principal por medio.

Answer (score 0):

Más o menos he soluiconado el tema, he cambiado la regla en el htaccess principal:
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dominio.es/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
por:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
PEro ahora el problema es que los dominios adicionales salen al final con dos barras invertidas //.